# JSON - array of objects into objects of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, functional-programming

I have a series of JSON entries:

```
[{"num": "1","name_A": "Alex" ,"name_B": "Bob"}, {"num": "2","name_A": "Anne" ,"name_B": "Barbra"}]
```

I am trying to convert this array of Objects as painlessly as possible into two objects - one with title name_A, and the second with the title name_B. Objects have to contain the title and an array of matching num-name pairs:

```
[{title: "name_A", names:[{"1", "Alex}, {"2", "Anne"}]}, {title:"name_B", names: [{"1", "Bob"}, {"2", "Barbra"}]}]
```

At first I tried simply to create two objects by reducing the array of object twice, once for name_A and second time for name_B and later glue everything together:

```
// get 'names' array
var name_A = objArray.reduce(function(memo, curr) {
    memo.push({curr.num, curr.name_A})
    return memo;
}, []);
```

But even this is failing. Why there is no push method for memo if I initialize reduce with an empty array?

And second question, am I on a right track or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: `{ "1", "Alex" }` is not a valid object. Object elements are all of the form `key: value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments inline, made a few minor corrections to the expectations.

```
var input = [{ "num": "1", "name_A": "Alex", "name_B": "Bob" }, { "num": "2", "name_A": "Anne", "name_B": "Barbra" }]

var output = input.reduce(function (a, b) {
    // construct new objects and set their properties
    var i = {};
    i[b.num] = b.name_A;
    var j = {};
    j[b.num] = b.name_B;

    // add them to our collection elements
    a[0].names.push(i);
    a[1].names.push(j);

    return a;
   // initializing our collection
}, [{ title: "name_A", names: [] }, { title: "name_B", names: [] }]);

// pretty print our output
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, "     "))
```

```js
var input = [{ "num": "1", "name_A": "Alex", "name_B": "Bob" }, { "num": "2", "name_A": "Anne", "name_B": "Barbra" }]

var output = input.reduce(function (a, b) {
  // construct new objects and set their properties
  var i = {};
  i[b.num] = b.name_A;
  var j = {};
  j[b.num] = b.name_B;

  // add them to our collection elements
  a[0].names.push(i);
  a[1].names.push(j);

  return a;
  // initializing our collection
}, [{ title: "name_A", names: [] }, { title: "name_B", names: [] }]);

so.log(output)
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
<script>
  var so = {
    log: function(o) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(o, null, "     ")
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `{ curr.num, curr.name_A }` is not a valid object, it's missing the property names. I've added properties `num` and `name` in my code below.

```
var name_A = [];
var name_B = [];
objArray.forEach(function(curr) {
    name_A.push({num: curr.num, name: curr.name_a});
    name_B.push({num: curr.num, name: curr.name_B});
});
var result = [ 
    { title: "name_A" }, names: name_A },
    ( title: "name_B" }, names: name_B }
];
```

Also, if you want to make an array out of the results of looping over an array, you should use `.map` rather than `.reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only property `num` is fixed. All other properties are treated as data, like `name_A` or `name_B`.

```js
var a = [{ "num": "1", "name_A": "Alex", "name_B": "Bob" }, { "num": "2", "name_A": "Anne", "name_B": "Barbra" }],
    result = [];
a.forEach(function (el) {
    var num = el.num;
    Object.keys(el).forEach(function (k) {
        function tryFindIndexAndSetNames(aa, i) {
            if (aa.title === k) {
                result[i].names[num] = el[k];
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (k !== 'num' && !result.some(tryFindIndexAndSetNames)) {
            var o = {};
            o[num] = el[k];
            result.push({ title: k, names: o });
        }
    });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```